# background-size не работает

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Сделал так, чтобы при наведении на ссылку в меню-навигации, появлялся задний фон... Хочу изменить размер этого фона, и что-то не получается. Ни `height`, ни `width`, ни `background-size` не срабатывают, в чём может быть проблема?

Вот что прописываю:

```
nav ul li a:hover{
    background: #e7e7e7;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-size: 450px;
}
```

К слову, ни один параметр в `background-size` не срабатывает, ни `%`, ни `px`, ни `cover`... Где искать проблему?

Вот скрин, на котором видно `a:hover`, размер которого я хочу поменять:

[image: hover background]
<sub>(источник: [screenshot.ru](http://screenshot.ru/950a046226eec2abd9bab1d67e53a39f.png))</sub>

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Effektiv Fox</title>
    <link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<header>
<nav>
    <ul class="navigation">
        <li><a href="#">О нас</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Цены</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Условия</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">История</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a id="foximg" href="index.html"><img src="fox.png" alt="effektiv fox" align="right"></a>
</nav>
</header>

<div id="mainboard">
    <br>
osdadsadadas    
</div>

<footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
background: #dedede;
 text-align: center;
}

header{
    background: #bababa;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 18,89px;
    color: #7a7a7a;
}

nav ul li a{
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #707070;
}

nav ul li a:hover{
    background: #e7e7e7;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-size: 450px;
}

#mainboard {
    background: #e7e7e7;
    height: 1000px; /* Высота блока */
    width: 1000px; /* Ширина блока */
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left;
    word-break: break-all;
}


.navigation {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 22px 0px 0px 20px;
}

#foximg {
    top: 1px; /* Расстояние от нижнего края окна браузера */
    position: absolute; /* Абсолютное позиционирование */
    left: 1365px;
   }
```

Comment: О каком заднем фоне речь? Судя по коду у вас нет никакого фонового изображения для ссылки.

Comment: @VitaliyShevchenko, через url фона не указано - да, но есть background: #e7e7e7;

nav ul li a:hover{
 background: #e7e7e7;
 border-radius: 10px;
 background-size: 450px;
}

Или background-size работает только при указном url? Если так, то как мне изменить размер background: #e7e7e7 в hover? 
Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @farVz Что-то непонятное Вы хотите сотворить. Меняйте размер самой ссылки, зачем эти фокусы с фоном? Да ещё и одноцветным фоном.

Comment: @VitaliyShevchenko, сотворить я пытаюсь то, чтобы hover был закруглен только сверху, а снизу оставался квадратным. 
![screenshot](http://screenshot.ru/37cc8250b5fdbfefd9355c03a74f9c6d.png)

Answer (score 2):

background-size применимо - если на фоне картинка, у тебя задан только цвет.
height и width - не срабатывают - потому что ссылка inline элемент - задай ему display: block;
Если ты при ховере - будешь менять padding - у тебя меню будет скакать.

Answer (score 1):

Ты можешь использовать свойство padding - размер внутренных отступов. Это полностью соответствует твоей задаче. Допиши к

```
nav ul li a:hover
```

что-нибудь в духе

```
padding: 15px;
```

Comment: Спасибо! Почти то, что мне нужно. Думаю и так сойдет... Чуть-чуть закругления снизу видно.

Answer (score 1):

Сделать закругления только сверху можно таким образом:

```
nav ul li a:hover{
    background: #e7e7e7;

    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: В моем случае хватило `padding: 10px 15px 20px 15px;` так как у меня цвет `<div>` и `a:hover` одинаковый. Ваш вариант тоже сработал, запомню на будущее!